# Transforming an exported mesh and its vertex normals to a new coordinate system

Tags: export, transforms

I have a mesh to be exported from Blender for use in an external software that I am working on which utilises DirectX. This exported mesh must include vertex positions, as well as vertex normal and tangent vectors.

The Cartesian coordinate basis differs between Blender and DirectX. The software has a function *f* comprised of two sequential rotations that transform the Blender coordinates to the DirectX basis. *f* is applied to the positions of all the imported mesh vertices so that the rendered mesh is oriented correctly. *f* is then applied to the imported normal and tangent data. The resulting mesh is oriented correctly, but the lighting is coming from the wrong direction relative to the mesh surface due to incorrectly oriented vector data.

If I am not mistaken, do I need to apply function *f* to the normal/tangent data twice: once to correct for the change in mesh surface direction when the vertex positions were reoriented, and again to transform the Cartesian basis of the vectors? I would appreciate someone checking my understanding here.

Comment: OGL and DX have different coordinate system *handedness*-- you can't go from one to the other with rotations alone.  You need a negative scale in one axis.  In addition, different software may compute the facing of a face in different ways: transforms do not change winding order, so a negative scale will flip facing; tangents and normals are probably (not necessarily) measured relative to this facing.  If you don't know your target software inside and out, just check your normals in it; if they're wrong, flip them.  Trial and error is perfectly reasonable when it's only two trials.

Comment: @Nathan At first I thought you were wrong because my model appears correctly in the software. But as it turns out, whilst the rotations I apply are correct, the X axis may indeed be incorrectly mirrored. I didn't notice before because my mesh is symmetrical along the X axis. I will try adding an X scale of -1 to the transform function and see if this fixes the issues.